# How to retrieve a record from a database and have it in order with the index from form load

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010

My first attempt at performing a search on records in a database; I have a windows form project that upon load event displays a name from an Access database in a textbox.  There is more to the form than this, but for practical purposes, I have buttons Previous, Next and a Find.  Suppose I have 4 names in the database: 1-Atlas, 2-Benson, 3-Lane & 4-Smith.  Form loads and Atlas is displayed.  Do a search for Lane and then Lane is displayed on the form.  Hit ‘Next’ and instead of Smith, Benson is displayed.  I know why it is doing so: the search puts the record in the DataRow ‘returnedRow’ whereas all the records displayed on form load and ‘Previous’ & ‘Next’ are from the DataRow ‘dRow’.  How do I retrieve a record from a query that is inside dRow?

```
OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection();
DataSet myDS;
int MaxRows = 0        
int inc = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        myConn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\Testing\TestDatabase.accdb";
        myConn.Open();
        myDS = new DataSet();
        string sql = "SELECT * From Test";
        OleDbDataAdapter myDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myConn);
        myDA.Fill(myDS, "People");
        NavigateRecords();
        MaxRows = myDS.Tables["People"].Rows.Count;
        myConn.Close();

    }
private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        DataRow dRow = myDS.Tables["People"].Rows[inc];

        txtName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        txtAddress.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
        txtCity.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
        txtState.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
        txtZip.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();  
    }
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (inc != MaxRows - 1)
        {
            inc++;
            NavigateRecords();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No more rows");
        }
    }
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchFor = txtFind.Text;
        int results = 0;

        if (txtFind.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to search for");
            return;
        }
        DataRow[] returnedRows;
        string expression;
        expression = "Name1='" + searchFor + "'";
        returnedRows = myDS.Tables["People"].Select(expression);
        results = returnedRows.Length;
        if (results > 0) 
        {
            DataRow dr1;
            dr1 = returnedRows[0];
            txtName.Text = dr1[1].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = dr1[2].ToString();
            txtCity.Text = dr1[3].ToString();
            txtState.Text = dr1[4].ToString();
            txtZip.Text = dr1[5].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No record found");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this part ... ?

```
private void NavigateRecords()
{
    DataRow dRow = myDS.Tables["People"].Rows[inc];

    txtName.Text = dRow[1];
    txtAddress.Text = dRow[2];
    txtCity.Text = dRow[3];
    txtState.Text = dRow[4];
    txtZip.Text = dRow[5];  
 }
```

Comment: That part displays the records at form load and is used when Next or Previous is selected.  But to do a search on the database returnedRows = myDS.Tables["People"].Select(expression); is used. returnedRows is an array whereas dRow is not.  If I try dRow = myDS.Tables["People"].Select(expression); in the Find I get "Cannot implicitly convert type DataRow[] to DataRow".